# Proper way to store my own access tokens/secrets on server

Tags: node.js, encryption, heroku, github, server

When you learn front-end development, the creed is to never store passwords on the client--only on the server/db. So now I'm building API's and using third-parties like Twitter and I'm realizing that since I'm using Github, and later pushing to Heroku, I have no place on the server to store my tokens/secrets (since Heroku pulls from Github I can't add to a .gitignore).

I've come to two solutions:

1) Store in a db.  That option seems trivial for smaller apps but scalability.
2) Encrypt the info on the server and upload that way.

What are the best practices when you have sensitive info, and are pushing to Heroku from Github?

Comment: Duplicate of http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/163506/how-does-one-handle-sensitive-data-when-using-github-and-heroku

Comment: Good find, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer here is this (for anyone who finds this thread): use Heroku environment variables.

Heroku encourages you to store any application specific sensitive information in environment variables. You can set these variables via the Heroku command line tool, or the Heroku dashboard.

If you'd like to set Heroku environment variables on the command line, you can do so like this:

```
$ heroku config:set MY_VARIABLE=my_value
```

That will store the environment variable.

Since you're using Node.js, you can then read the value of these variables in your Heroku code by doing something like this:

```
console.log(process.env.MY_VARIABLE);
```

In Node, you can access environment variables via `process.env` as an object =)